# iOS Applications through OTA cannot be download at this time

Tags: ios, iphone, ota

I have an iPhone application that is to be distributed in-house through Enterprise account.

The Application is available trough a link that works fine for some users and for the others it fails with "Cannot be download at this time" knowing that both users have the same iPhone model, iOS version and settings.

Is there a way for me to get more details about the root cause of not being able to download. tried the device log but it is so overwhelming and keep updating so it is difficult to capture the logs related to the download failure.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: _Usually_ the 'Cannot be download at this time' error is about provisioning profiles.. You're using in-house through, but could be worth a double check. Also, try connecting the phone through Organiser in Xcode. You can view device logs through there, may be worth a try.

Comment: It is working fine for some devices and not for others. so i doubt it has to do with the provision profile. and the device log seems to be overwhelming with messages that keep updating. so it is kind of difficult to capture the messages related only to the download process.